# Getting so many Exceptions while running the kafka connect worker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Getting so many exceptions while running the Kafka Connect worker.
I have set all the worker properties and all the jar paths looks fine.

The exceptions are below:

```
2020-07-23 18:41:58 WARN  Reflections:104 - could not create Dir
   using jarFile from url
   file:/kafka/bin/../clients/build/libs/kafka-clients*.jar. skipping.  
   java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:213)                                                                                                                           
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:155)                                                                                                                           
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)                                                                                                                           
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)                                                                                                                           
at org.reflections.vfs.Vfs$DefaultUrlTypes$1.createDir(Vfs.java:216)                                                                                                        
at org.reflections.vfs.Vfs.fromURL(Vfs.java:99)                                                                                                                             
at org.reflections.vfs.Vfs.fromURL(Vfs.java:91)                                                                                                                             
at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:240)                                                                                                                   
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.scan(DelegatingClassLoader.java:373)                                                
at org.reflections.Reflections$1.run(Reflections.java:198)                                                                                                                  
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)                                                                                                  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)                                                                                                                 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)                                                                                          
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)                                                                                          
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)  
2020-07-23 18:41:58 WARN  Reflections:377 - could not create Vfs.Dir from url. ignoring the exception and continuing         
                                                
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: Could not open url connection at org.reflections.vfs.JarInputDir$1$1.<init>(JarInputDir.java:37)                                                                                                      
at org.reflections.vfs.JarInputDir$1.iterator(JarInputDir.java:33)                                                                                                      
at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:243)                                                                                                               
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.scan(DelegatingClassLoader.java:373)                                            
at org.reflections.Reflections$1.run(Reflections.java:198)                                                                                                              
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)                                                                                              
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)                                                                                                             
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)                                                                                      
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)                                                                                      
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)  
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /kafka/bin/../clients/build/libs/kafka-clients*.jar (No such file or directory)

   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)                                                                                                                             
   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)                                                                                                               
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)                                                                                                         -
```

`kafkaconnectsladev.log`

Comment: What version are you running? Where did you install it from?

Comment: Downloaded Kafka from  https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/1.1.0/kafka_2.11-1.1.0.tgz

Comment: The _scala_ version is 2.11. The Kafka version is 1.1.0. You're better off using the latest version (2.5.0): https://kafka.apache.org/downloads

Comment: The same combination  is working on azure VM's , now same i am trying to run on docker container , there i am getting these exceptions
(I am new to kafka)

Comment: if you want a Docker container then just use the provided images: https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base

Comment: but why this version should work right?
Can please provide solution for this version only,  most of our prod applications are running same version.

Comment: The compatible version of the image for Apache Kafka 1.1 is `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:4.1.4`.

Comment: Tried with latest version as well, still same error
(This is one of the exceptions-----)
2020-07-24 15:31:33 WARN  Reflections:396 - could not get type for name javax.mail.Authenticator from any class loader
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name javax.mail.Authenticator
\\n

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.Authenticator

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Comment: It sounds very much like you've built your own Docker image incorrectly. Maybe edit your question with a step-by-step list of how you built and run the image, and from there we can see what's gone wrong. Or, just use one of the pre-built ones …

Comment: ERROR Worker:498 - Graceful stop of task SLA_INCIDENT_SCHEDULE_TOPICMongo_SR-0 failed.

Do you know about this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, yes these are all warnings and with newer version of the kafka client library, i am not seeing these.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31840940)

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing `WARN Reflections`, then this is a warning, and not an error, and it is safe to ignore.

You can edit the `log4j.properties` file to silence the warnings, if you want. Using the Confluent Docker images, this is done via the `CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS` variable